# PrintDocument PrintToFile to memorystream

Tags: c#, printdocument

The method PrintToFile of the PrintDocument sends the print output to a file instead of a port. 
Is it possible to send the output to a memorystream instead of creating a physical file?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible by using RedMon ( redirection port monitor ): http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/redmon/

You can configure it to print out to the '[stdout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams)' and then to run the application that you will write that reads out what RedMon wrote to the '[stdout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams)'. That should not be to complicated.